# I want to use mediaplayer for recording the sounds and then want to calculate the "amplitude" for moving Bars up and down with the change in sound

Tags: android, handler, android-mediarecorder

I want to use MediaRecorder for recording the sounds and then want to calculate the "amplitude"  for moving Bars up and down with  the change in sound.I haven't Founded any proper solution yet. any suggestions.?? Edited: I managed to get my hand into it now the problem is i have Tried getMaxAmplitude() to find amplitude using Handler after that i am trying to use that value to show a bar movement up it did nt work then i printed the value of getMaxAmplitude() certainly the value comes out to be zero.what could be wrong here.?? Here is the piece of code
     public void run() {
            try {

```
            mRecorder.start();
            while (this.mIsRunning) {
                // creating these variables here so that
                // the mode change can be handled
                double amp = getAmplitude();
                Message msg = mHandle.obtainMessage(MY_MSG, amp);
                mHandle.sendMessage(msg);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Message msg = mHandle.obtainMessage(ERROR_MSG,
                    e.getLocalizedMessage() + "");
            mHandle.sendMessage(msg);
        }
        if (mRecorder != null) {
            mRecorder.stop();
            mRecorder.release();
            mRecorder = null;
        }
    }

    public double getAmplitude() {
        if (mRecorder != null) {
            powerDb = 20 * Math.log10(mRecorder.getMaxAmplitude() / 2700.0);
            return (powerDb);
        }

        else {
            return 1;
        }
    }
public Handler mhandle = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
            case MY_MSG:

                // mSplModeTV.setText(" " + msg.obj);
                if (audioEngineFlag == 1) {
                    String s1 = msg.obj.toString();
                    float f = Float.valueOf(s1.trim()).floatValue();
                    Log.v(TAG, "amplitude=" + f); }
```

Comment: Great no one is there to help..!!! atleast let me know what to do.. if i want to call getMaxAmplitue() after every .5 sec. inside a handler how can i get the reading continuously..??

Answer (score 0):

you can use timer to call getMaxAmplitue() after every .5 sec

```
MyTimer tim = new new MyTimer(30000,500);;
   mRecorder.start();
tim.start();
            while (this.mIsRunning) {
                // creating these variables here so that
                // the mode change can be handled
                double amp = getAmplitude();
                Message msg = mHandle.obtainMessage(MY_MSG, amp);
                mHandle.sendMessage(msg);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Message msg = mHandle.obtainMessage(ERROR_MSG,
                    e.getLocalizedMessage() + "");
            mHandle.sendMessage(msg);
        }
        if (mRecorder != null) {
            mRecorder.stop();
            mRecorder.release();
            mRecorder = null;
        }
    }

    public double getAmplitude() {
        if (mRecorder != null) {
            powerDb = 20 * Math.log10(mRecorder.getMaxAmplitude() / 2700.0);
            return (powerDb);
        }

        else {
            return 1;
        }
    }
public Handler mhandle = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
            case MY_MSG:

                // mSplModeTV.setText(" " + msg.obj);
                if (audioEngineFlag == 1) {
                    String s1 = msg.obj.toString();
                    float f = Float.valueOf(s1.trim()).floatValue();
                    Log.v(TAG, "amplitude=" + f); }


public class MyTimer extends CountDownTimer {
        public MyTimer(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
            super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            int amplitude = mRecorder.getMaxAmplitude();
            Log.i("AMPLITUDE", new Integer(amplitude).toString());
        }
    }
```

You can use this handler in timer to get the result after every .5 sec.